# Converting sympy.core.symbol.Symbol to float

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

For calcuation regarding a photobioreactor size I have a sympy solve routine running, giving me correct results for some concentrations (O2Lout and O2Gout). The results are provided as a sympy.core.symbol.Symbol type. 
This is not convenient since a want to have the whole solve routine in a for loop for reach value of 'Kola' and 'V_collumn' and store the results of each loop. If I can convert the solve results to a float or similar I can store the results in a variable at to get a nice overview for further calculations. How can i do this?

```
m=31.7
O2Lin=3.5*0.26
O2Gin=9.4
Fg=0.0012
Fl=0.02
Kola=[0.24478129, 0.12676818, 0.0811683]
V_collumn=[0.003925, 0.010048, 0.018997]


O2Lout, O2Gout = symbols('O2Lout O2Gout')
eq1 = Eq(Fl*(O2Lin-O2Lout)+Fg*(O2Gin-O2Gout))
eq2 = Eq(Fg*(O2Gin-O2Gout)-Kola[0]*(O2Gout/m-O2Lout)*V_collumn[0])
solve((eq1,eq2), (O2Lout, O2Gout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from solve here is just a dict. You can use the symbols as keys into the dict to get the corresponding values as Float:

```
In [37]: d = solve((eq1,eq2), (O2Lout, O2Gout))                                                                                   

In [38]: d                                                                                                                        
Out[38]: {O2Gout: 9.85762616826896, O2Lout: 0.882542429903862}

In [39]: d[O2Gout]                                                                                                                
Out[39]: 9.85762616826896
```